# Django encoding problems with CSV

Tags: python, django, csv, encoding, decoding

File export works well, but I have a problem with encoding data. 
Where I made ​​mistakes?

My code is

```
for user in users:
    result = user[0].encode('utf-8')
    for x in filter(lambda q: q is not None, user):
        result += ', '
        if type(x) in (str, unicode):
            result += x.encode('utf-8')
        else:
            result += str(x)
        print type(result), result
    writer.writerow(result)

return response
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Define "I have a problem." Did you get an error/traceback? Show it. CSV is notorious for not handling Unicode well in the Python 2 library, so many use `unicodecsv`. Are you using Python 2 or 3? Not enough information here to help you....

Comment: No, I have a problem in exported file. I'm using python 2.7

Now, data in file looks like

Имя Фамилия Комментарий Дата контракта
� � � �
� � � �

Answer (score 0):

The .encode method gets applied to a Unicode string to make a byte-string; if your CSV data is NOT in utf-8, and instead encoded let's say in latin-1, then you need a "transcoding". Something like this:

```
line.decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8')
```

if you know your CSV encoding, then replace latin-1 with whatever your input data encoding is.

Also, if you are not sure what the CSV file's encoding is then you may want consider using [chardet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) and you can learn about how to use it at [readthedocs](http://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)

Comment: I used 

`writer.writerow([x.encode('utf-8') for x in filter(lambda q: q is not None, user)])`

but, this method works not for all values